# How to populate ListView with db in asset folder?

Tags: sqlite, listview, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

so I want to make an app that lists foods that I have stored in an already existing SQLite database I created. I have my foodDB.db file in the /assets/databases folder.

I know I must use a DatabaseHelper class. I have done my fair share of research, I have looked at plenty of stackoverflow posts and youtube tutorials but none satisfy my critera of populating a ListView from an existing database in the asset folder. I find them very confusing and not clear.

Could someone please clearly explain to me how I would go about this? I am really struggling and would appreciate some guidance.

My database is called `foodDatabase.db`.
My database contains 1 table called `dataset`.
The table `dataset` contains the colums: `id, name, description, protein, fat, carbohydrates, energy, starch, sugar, cholesterol`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a few points to be noted.

- 1 - you have said that the file is **FoodDB.db** but then said that the database is called **foodDatabase.db**. The database name is the file name. As such the following example uses **FoodDB.db** as the file that is in the assets (you could rename the file when copying from the assets but I've not done that in this answer.)
- 2 - You do not need a Database Helper and the example doesn't use one.

The are two parts :-

- 1) Accessing the database to extract the data for the ListView. In the following example this is copied from the assets to the standard database location (***/data/data/the_package/databases/the_database_name***).

  - The assumption has been made that once copied from the assets the database will then subsequently be used (i.e it is copied once for the lifetime of the App).
- 2) Displaying the extracted data (obtained as a Cursor) in a ListView.

To do 2 you will need the layout to include a ListView, as such the following layout has been used. **activity_main.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="fooddb.so49328656populatelistview.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/foodlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

- Note `tools:context="fooddb.so49328656populatelistview.MainActivity"` would have to reflect **YOUR package**

The Database Helper -  **Not used as warned**

The invoking activity **MainActivity.java** (see notes) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String DBNAME = "FoodDB.db";
    static final String DBASSETPATH = "databases/" + DBNAME;
    static final String FOODTABLE = "dataset";
    static final String FOODCOLUMN = "Food";
    static final String IDCOLUMN = "ID";

    ListView mFoodList;
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    Cursor mCsr;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFoodList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.foodlist);
        mDB = openFoodDB();
        if (mDB != null) {
            mCsr = mDB.query(FOODTABLE,
                    new String[]{IDCOLUMN + " AS _id",
                            FOODCOLUMN
                    },
                    null,null,null,null,null);
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mCsr,
                    new String[]{FOODCOLUMN},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0);
            mFoodList.setAdapter(mSCA);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to open Database.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase openFoodDB() {
        String dbpath = this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
        if (this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).exists()) {
            Log.d("OPENFOODDB","Opening already existing Database");
            return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        InputStream is;
        byte[] buffer;
        FileOutputStream db;
        try {
             is =  this.getAssets().open(DBASSETPATH);
             buffer = new byte[is.available()];
             is.read(buffer);
             is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("OPENFOODDB","Unable to locate or buffer input from assets " + DBASSETPATH);
            return null;
        }
        // Just in case the databases directory doesn't exist create it.
        File dbmkdir = (this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME)).getParentFile();
        dbmkdir.mkdirs();
        try {
            db = new FileOutputStream(this.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("OPENFOODDB","Unable to create outputstream for DB at path " + dbpath);
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
            return null;
        }
        try {
            db.write(buffer);
            db.flush();
            db.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("OPENFOODDB","Failed to copy asset to DB");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- the `openFoodDB` method returns the SQLiteDatabase after copying if from the assets file if the database does not exist. The method will return null if there were issues.

  - if the database exists then the log will contain a message like  `D/OPENFOODDB: Opening already existing Database`
  - there will be no log messages if the database was copied from the assets file and opened successfully. Messages will only be logged if there is an issue.
  - if for example the assets file is missing then you would get a message in the log like `D/OPENFOODDB: Unable to locate or buffer input from assets databases/FoodDB.db` this would be preceded with a stack trace

e.g. :-

```
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: databases/FoodDB.db
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at fooddb.so49328656populatelistview.MainActivity.openFoodDB(MainActivity.java:63)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at fooddb.so49328656populatelistview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-16 22:17:04.008 1529-1529/? W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

- A CursorAdapter requires a column specifically named **_id** hence the use of `IDCOLUMN + " AS _id"`.

### The Result :-

[image]

Comment: hi mike, sorry for the late reply. I have done as you said but it still does not work. I have noticed that my foodDB.db file looks like this when I open it. [link](https://gyazo.com/900076adbb190d83bee62d18cc956733) . Is this wrong?

Comment: also I created a new project and named it the exact same as yours. so the only difference would be the db file we are using. On the `tools:context=` line in the activity_main.xml file. you said it must reflect my package. so to my understanding mine should be this? `tools:context="com.example.tom.so49328656populatelistview.MainActivity"` although i misunderstood this. hope to hear from you again soon. thanks for you initial respones :)

Comment: You cannot use Android Studio to open SQLite databases it has no inbuilt handler (however the screenshot appears to show a valid SQLite database i.e. first 16 characters appear to be ***SQLite format 3\000*** as per [Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)). The case of the file name is taken into consideration so `static final String DBNAME = "FoodDB.db";` would have to be changed to `static final String DBNAME = "foodDB.db";` (lowercase **f** for the first character).

Comment: can you look at the other comment I added about the `tools:context` line. I'm getting 'E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module' error in Logcat when I run the app.

Comment: Just create the layout as a new one, all you need is the ListView with an id of foodlist e.g. `<ListView
        android:id="@+id/foodlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>`. The ensure that in the MainActivity that `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` reflects the layout.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I noticed that `mFoodList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.foodlist);` Says "Casting this.findViewById(R.id.foodlist is redundant."     Also on tutorials I have looked at people don't use the asset/database directory. Just copy the db into the asset folder? I'm just trying to work out why it worked fine for you but not for me.

Comment: I cast to ListView just in case someone is using a older version of Android Studio, it being redundant isn't a failure (just saying you don't need to cast). Some use asset some use database directory. The if the latter then path should be databases/name_of_the_file else just name_of_the_file. I don't believe that the `can't load memtrack` is the issue.